# How to vertically align cells in a table slightly?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

This is the latex code for my document[image: This is what the code generates]

I am trying to figure out how Ii can slightly adjust b so that it is slightly lower compared to a & c. Whenever I try anything, I find online I end up adjusting the whole line since it is a table row.

What I want is them all in 1 row but misaligned slightly(maximum 1pt).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in, top =1in, bottom =.75in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.15cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6\baselineskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=.1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=.7\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X  }
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\Large \textbf{heading} }\\
a & b & c \\ \hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
a & b & c \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raisebox{-1pt}{b}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by David Carlisle

```
\raisebox{-1pt}{b}
```

this works and solves my problem.